# Unauthorized: No valid token provided

Tags: reactjs, node.js, authentication, mern

I am building full stack MERN project, frontend is done now it's time for backend.

There is school registration which is working properly and data is getting updated to database (MongoDB Atlas) once new school logs in.
But issue arises when the same school is trying to log in to portal with credentials.

School Login is in following way:

1. There is React page called `SchoolLogin` where user fills and submit the credentials.
2. There is `WelcomeAfterSchoolLogin`, for successful login.
3. There is token generation and storing in cookies in router file named `auth.js` where all the routing is done.
4. There is middleware called `authenticate.js` which checks the generated token with `SECRET_KEY` in `config.env` file.
5. In `WelcomeAfterSchoolLogin`, there is `useEffect()`.

All the code snippet I am providing is in the same sequence.

What I observed is token is generating properly and getting stored in cookies properly.

1. SchoolLogin Page

   ```
   export default function SchoolLogin() {

     const navigate = useNavigate();

     const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false); 
     const [password, setPassword] = useState(""); 

     const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
       setShowPassword((prevShowPassword) => !prevShowPassword);
     };

     const [udisecode, setUdiseCode] = useState('');
     const [email, setEmail] = useState('');

     const submitLogin = async (e) => {
       e.preventDefault();

       try {
         const res = await fetch('/schoollogin', {
           method: "POST",
           headers: {
             "Content-Type": "application/json"
           },
           body: JSON.stringify({
             udisecode, email, password
           })
         });

         const data = await res.json();

         if (res.status === 422 || !data) {
           window.alert("Enter the Data!");
         } 

         else if (res.status === 400) {
           window.alert("SCHOOL NOT REGISTERED WITH THIS UDISE CODE");
         } 

         else if (res.status === 401) { 
           window.alert("INVALID CREDENTIALS");
         } 

         else if (res.status === 200) { 
           window.alert("Success");
           navigate('/welcomeafterschoollogin');
         }

       } catch (error) {
         console.error("Error parsing JSON:", error);
       }
     };
   ```
2. WelcomeAfterSchoolLogin Page

   ```
   export default function WelcomeAfterSchoolLogin() {

     const navigate = useNavigate();
     const [schoolData, setSchooData] = useState();

     const callWelcomeAfterSchoolLoginPage = async () => {
       try {
           const res = await fetch('/welcomeafterschoollogin', {
               method: "GET",
               headers: {
                   Accept: "application/json",
                   "Content-Type": "application/json"
               },
               credentials: "include"
           });

           if (res.status !== 200) {
               console.log('Unauthorized: No valid token provided');
               throw new Error('Unauthorized: No valid token provided');
           }

           const data = await res.json();
           console.log(data);
           setSchooData(data)

       } catch (err) {
           console.log(err)
           console.log('Error:', err.message);
           navigate('/schoollogin');
           // navigate('/welcomeafterschoollogin');
       }
   }

     useEffect(() => {
       callWelcomeAfterSchoolLoginPage();
     }, []);


     return (
       <section id="about">
         <div className="container-fluid px-0">
           <div className="container mb-md-0 mt-5">
           <form method="GET"></form>
             <h1 className="au-text">Welcome {schoolData?.schoolname} to <img src={KoshishLogo} width="180" className="logo" style={{width: "13rem", marginTop: '-0.5rem', marginLeft: '0rem'}} /></h1>

             {/* Row 1 */}
             <img src={Vector4} alt="Vector4" className="Vector4" />
             <div className="row mt-lg-3 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center">
               <div className="col-lg-12 col-md-12 mt-3 aboutus-main-card-center">

               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         </div>
       </section>
     );
   }
   ```
3. Token generation and storing in cookies

   ```
   router.post("/schoollogin", async (req, res) => {
       try {
           const { udisecode, email, password } = req.body;

           if (!udisecode || !email || !password) {
               return res.status(422).json({ message: "Please fill all the details" });
           }

           const isSchoolExist = await School.findOne({ udisecode: udisecode });

           if (isSchoolExist) {
               const token = isSchoolExist.generateAuthToken()
               console.log(token)

               res.cookie("jwtoken", token, {
                   expires: new Date(Date.now() + 2592000000),
                   httpOnly: true,
               });

               const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, isSchoolExist.password);

               if (!passwordMatch) {
                   return res.status(401).json({ message: "INVALID CREDENTIALS" });
               } else {
                   console.log(isSchoolExist);
                   return res.status(200).json({ message: "Login Successfully" });
               }
           } 

           else {
               console.log("ERROR");
               return res.status(400).json({ message: "YOU DON'T HAVE A SCHOOL REGISTERED ACCOUNT" });
           }

       } catch (err) {
           console.error(err);
           res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal Server Error" });
       }
   });
   ```
4. Midddleware auth.js

   ```
   const Authenticate = async (req, res, next) => {
       try {
           const token = req.cookies.jwtoken;
           const verifyToken = jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET_KEY)

           const rootUser = await School.findOne({_id: verifyToken._id, "tokens.token": token})

           if (!rootUser) {
               throw new Error('User not found!')
           }

           req.token = token
           req.rootUser = rootUser
           req.userID = rootUser._id

           next();

       } catch (err) {
           res.status(401).json({ error: 'Unauthorized: No valid token provided' });
           console.log(err)
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: _"frontend is done now its time for backend"_ - FYI that's really not a smart way to go about building out a system. Think thin vertical slices.